# Parallel arithmetic on large integers

Tags: math, parallel-processing

Are there any software tools for performing arithmetic on very large numbers in parallel? What I mean by parallel is that I want to use all available cores on my computer for this.

The constraints are wide open for me. I don't mind trying any language or tech.

Please and thanks.

Comment: Do you mean to parallelize the individual arithmetic operations? I guess that kind of fine-grained parallelism would likely cause enough overhead due to synchronization and cache invalidations to outweight the gain. Better to parallelize larger chunks of algorithm, in which case this is not specific to big numbers.

Comment: Yes that is what I mean. I am trying to divide a very large number and it takes hours on one of my cores.

Comment: You are trying to divide *one* very large number?  Or you have a bunch of very large numbers you wish to apply division to? (The former will require you to find some algebraic law about the nature of the steps of division, to partition the computation.  The latter you can implement as an embarassingly parallel operation over the individual divisions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are either dividing really huge numbers, or are using a suboptimal algorithm. Parallelizing things to a fixed number of cores will only tweak the constants, but have no effect on the asymptotic behavior of your operation. And if you're talking about hours for a single division, asymptotic behavior is what matters most. So I suggest you *first* make sure sure your asymptotic complexity is as good as can be, and *then* start looking for ways to improve the constants, perhaps by parallelizing.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algorithm#Large_integer_methods) suggests Barrett division, and [GMP has a variant of that](https://gmplib.org/manual/Block_002dWise-Barrett-Division.html). I'm not sure whether what you've tried so far is on a similar level, but unless you are sure that it is, I'd give GMP a try.

See also [Parallel Modular Multiplication on Multi-core Processors](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/ARITH.2013.20) for recent research. Haven't read into that myself, though.

Answer (score 0):

The only effort I am aware of is a CUDA library called [CUMP](http://www.hpcs.cs.tsukuba.ac.jp/~nakayama/cump/). However, the library only provides support  for addition, subtraction and multiplication. Anyway, you can use multiplication to perform the division on the GPU and check if the quality of the result is enough for your particular problem.